# Is the concept of karma fair or unfair?

Tags: karma

So basically I was wondering if there are any flaws to the concept of karma. 
 For example when we see someone being ill-treated or victimized, do we tell them it is because of wrong-doing on their part in a past life?

Comment: do we tell them it is because of wrong-doing on their part in a past life?   --- Im not sure if you shd tell them that or not when they are in misery but that's the reason the Hindu scriptures give

Comment: very loosely put, yes you can say karma is „fair“: your reap what you sow